# How to debug CGI over fcgiwrap/nginx

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, cgi, debugging

I serve executable scripts (mainly in C) through `fcgiwrap` connected with `nginx`. Since the scripts are complied, I can get the coding errors during compilation, but sometimes I receive `CGI` errors simply stating

```
An error occurred while reading CGI reply (no response received)
```

Is there any debugging approach to identify what is wrong with the CGI request/proces?

How can I set a debugging system to deliver the errors into the nginx log?

Comment: Had the same error a few days ago. In my case this was caused by a segfault in the c++-program.
Unfortunately the nginx-logs aren't very helpful, so I have to use my internal logger.

Answer (score 0):

I put a `sleep(10);` in my C program. Start GDB with your program and set a breakpoint to the command behind the sleep. Then submit your cgi programm in a browser and enter `ps axu | grep prog`. Type `attach <pid>` in gdb, you need to do this fast, you have only 10 seconds. Then you can debug your program.