# Nginx & fcgiwrap, logging perl errors to error log

Tags: nginx, perl, spawn-fcgi

This is similar to this question, which got no responses:
[How to debug CGI over fcgiwrap/nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/532499/how-to-debug-cgi-over-fcgiwrap-nginx)

How do I get perl errors to be automatically placed in the nginx error log? Right now, when there is any perl error, the following message goes in the error log:

```
2014/05/11 22:43:48 [error] 1730#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: localhost, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
```

This is completely useless for debugging. I can use something like CGI::Carp qw{fatalsToBrowser}, but this is not optimal. It would be better to have it logged to a server-side file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822787/how-can-i-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-log-file-in-perl) to send both STDOUT and STDERR to any log file you have access to write to, including your nginx error.log.  Though it'd likely be more helpful to send it to a different file.  Simply remove the STDOUT entries, if you only want STDERR output.

Comment: Please provide the relevant content *here* and link elsewhere for more details (and for attribution).